# React - Toggle theme from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project on react but I have ran into an issue.

The issue I am having is that I need to be able to toggle my "dark" and "light" theme from a icon that is in a different component. This icon exists in my `BottomNavigation` but the function for switching the theme exists in my `app.js`.

Did some research on my own and found that I need to "lift the state up". Issue is that I need to lift it twice as my files look like this:

```
./Components
  ./Home.js
    - (components gets added here)
  ./Navigation
    ./BottomNavigation.js

app.js
(/home is added here)
```

My app.js looks like:

```
function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const themeToggler = () => {
    theme === "light" ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light");
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/account">
          <Account />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

My Home.js looks like:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const [showingState, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <TopNavigation isShowing={(showingState) => setIsShowing(showingState)} />
      <BottomNavigation />
      <ImageSlider />
      <Grid />
      {showingState && (
        <CurrencyPopup
          isShowing={(showingState) => setIsShowing(showingState)}
        />
      )}
      <BestSeller />
      <CollectionPromo />
      <Instagram />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My BottomNavigation.js looks like (only took the part with the icon):

```
<div className={classes.options_container}>
  <IconApp className={classes.icon_container}>
    <span className={classes.cart_sum}>$0.00</span>
    <Cart className={classes.icon} />
  </IconApp>
  <IconApp className={classes.icon_container}>
    <Heart className={classes.icon} />
  </IconApp>
  <IconApp className={classes.icon_container}>
    <Visibility
      onClick={() => props.setTheme("")} //This icon shall switch the theme
      className={classes.icon}
    />
  </IconApp>
  <IconApp className={classes.icon_container}>
    <a href="/account">
      <User className={classes.icon} />
    </a>
  </IconApp>
</div>
```

If you have any ideas or need something more from the code, let me know!

Comment: This is the sort of situation where I would suggest looking into [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) since it will likely be used throughout your app. (In fact, dark mode is the example they use to explain context in the documentation)

Comment: @DBS ahh I see! I'll take a look at it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For best practice, you have a few options:

1. Use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples).
2. Use a state management library like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/).

You definitely don't want to life state up in your case, because the two components are too far away from each other in the hierarchy.

Comment: Checked some stuff out when it came to Context. In my scenario I need to check if the icon has been pressed, which I can do with an `onClick`. I don't really understand it yet. But get the principle. As I said, I need it to check if the icon has been pressed. Does that mean the icon becomes the provider and then my `app.js` becomes the consumer?

Comment: The link I attached is an example usage of Context which is exactly about toggling theme. That should help you.

Comment: I tested it for a bit but did not get it to work, do not understand it. I think that the part I'm not really getting is that how do I make my icon become that "toggleTheme" function?

Answer (score 0):

Lifting state up would be solution that does not require any additional knowledge.
However, its excessive use (over three or more component) is a bad practice, since it makes code dirty

Using RecoilJS would be easiest, since its api is nearly identical to that of `useState`, and there is less work for you to do

Sticking to vanilla ReactJS, try React Context